# textLabel hidding detailLabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView` with dynamic cell using the "Right Detail" Style. But when the `textLabel` has high width he hides the `detailLabel`.

I've tried to resize the `textLabel` but it seems to be unresizable. Is there a way to do it while avoiding to subclass `UITableViewCell` or adding by myself some `UILabel` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom label in cell.Increase height of cell if still face problem.

Here is my code
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];  
NSDictionary *dict=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *strName=[dict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *strType = [dict objectForKey:@"type"];
cell.selectionStyle = NO;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=1;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
UILabel *lbl =[[UILabel alloc]init];
lbl.frame=CGRectMake(115,8,220,40);
lbl.text=strName;
lbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0f green:64/255.0f blue:34/255.0f alpha:1.0];
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
}
else
{
    lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
}
lbl.baselineAdjustment=UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
lbl.numberOfLines=1;
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *lbl1 =[[UILabel alloc]init];
lbl1.frame=CGRectMake(115,35,220,40);
lbl1.text=strType;
lbl1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74/255.0f green:64/255.0f blue:34/255.0f alpha:1.0];
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    lbl1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
}
else
{
    lbl1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
}
lbl1.baselineAdjustment=UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
lbl1.numberOfLines=1;
lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


[[cell contentView] addSubview:lbl];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:lbl1];
return cell;

[cell release];
[CellIdentifier release];
[lbl release];
```

}

Comment: @ keyur bhalodiya Not need much kind of code  only need  a precise code. do not just copy paste here directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resize a `UILabel` by changing its frame. Alternatively, use the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property. See the documentation: [UILabel Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Comment: I do `[cell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 30)]` but the UILabel still to big.                                                edit : I logged the width and with the code above I have a 320px width

Comment: Maybe you don't have what you think you have.  How can the width be 320 when you've set it to 10?  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You absolutely understood what I mean :) I set the width to 10, but when I tried to log it into the consol log, the width was set to 320 ! I have found a post about it and it seems that this label can not be resized (I dont have the link right now).